# Basic OOP PHP form class

Tags: php, forms, oop

I'm just experimenting with OOP programming I'm trying to create a form class. I'm unable to print the checkbox, how can I check where things are going wronge?

```
  require_once('form.php');
  $gender = new Checkbox('Please select your gender','gender',array('male','female'));
  echo $gender->show_checkbox();
```

File with class:

```
class Inputfield{

  public $id;
  public $options_array;
  public $question;
  public $type;
  function __construct($newquestion,$newid,$newoptions_array){
    $this->question=$newquestion;
    $this->id=$newid;
    $this->type="txt";
    $this->options_array=$newoptions_array;
  }
  public function show_options($options_arr,$type,$id,$classes){
    $output="";
    foreach($options_arr as $option){
        $output.="<label for=\"".$option."\"></label><input name=\"".$option."\" type=\"".$type."\" id=\"".$id."\" class=\"".$classes."\">";
    }
    return $output;
  }
  public function show_question(){
    $output="<h3 class='question'>".$this->vraag."</h3>";
    return $output;
  }
}
class Checkbox extends Inputfield{
  function __construct($newquestion,$newid,$newoptions_array){
    $this->question=$newquestion;
    $this->id=$newid;
    $this->type="checkbox";
    $this->options_array=$newoptions_array;
  }

  public function show_checkbox(){
    $output=show_question();
    $output.=show_options($this->options_array,'checkbox',$this->id,'class');
    return $output;
  }
}
```

Comment: what about enabling your error_reporting and display_errors ini setting?

Comment: Just as a piece of advice, I think you should rename your `show_checkbox()` method to something more generic like `render()`, and also write a `render()` method for the InputField class. That will enable you to extend InputField in as many classes as you want, and to loop over many objects inheriting from InputField and call their `render()` method without having to know what they really are. Look into [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) for more details on that.

Answer (score 5):

1. You call instance methods with `$this`: `$this->show_options();`
2. You don't need to copy-paste the whole constructor as soon as it's identical to the one in parent class

   1. In case if it matches partially you can call it like `parent::__construct(...)` and then define a custom `$this->type="checkbox";`
   2. You can not define it in runtime but specify it as a property default value.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `$this` in an object context. Eg. in your `show_checkbox` method, write:

```
$output = $this->show_question();
$output .= $this->show_options(...);
```